# Can you lookup a domains past nameserver & mx record history?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, mx-record

If is possible to find out which nameservers a domain was previously pointing too?
I need to try and find where a domain was previously hosted so that I can try and gain access to an old hosted email account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 40):

http://whoisrequest.org/history/

This one is really cool . No registration needed .

Comment: WhoisRequest.org is really cool, thank you for that link.

Comment: Only works for com, net, org, info, biz and us domains.  For others try using http://dnshistory.org

Answer (score 17):

http://dnshistory.org/

Seems to have a patchy history, all for free.

Comment: I am unable to find history of my domain

Comment: Site says they closed down on July 10, 2016.

Comment: This site will shut down on the 10th July 2016 due to funding issues.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another one
https://completedns.com/dns-history/

It does support a lot of domain TLDs - [list of supported TLDs](https://completedns.com/supported_tlds).

With the free account you can make up to **100 queries** for nameserver history.

Comment: works for .SE and .NU as well

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no - I'm not aware of any [Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php) for DNS records, but it'd be cool if I was wrong.

Do you have any old emails with full headers to or from that domain?  Transport headers may be your only hope.

Comment: Good news @shane-madden! You are wrong!
I found a WHOIS History Function on [domaintools.com](http://domaintools.com) that saved the day. It is one of their Pro tools unfortunately so you have to pay for it but they do offer a free 3 day trial which helped me out on this occasion.

Comment: @Luke, it's worth noting that their database is extremely incomplete, as it was built on the fly based on lookups passing through their systems. As a result, it's somewhat useable for US domains but very nearly useless for 90% of the world.

Answer (score 2):

If [DNS History](http://dnshistory.org/) or [WhoIS Domain History Checker](http://whoisrequest.com/history/) don't work out for you, try [DNS Trails](http://www.dnstrails.com). They seem to have a bigger history database and I was able to find records I couldn't with the others.

None of the services require signup.

Comment: DNS Trails is the best of all recommended services.

Answer (score 1):

For **.se** domains, the [DNSCheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/) tool checks if the previous DNS servers are still authoritative, which means you can see what they were in the "Advanced Results" tab.

Answer (score 1):

I found a WHOIS History Function on domaintools.com that lets you view a pretty comprehensive history of the domains whois changes. It is a part of their Pro tools however which does come at a cost.

It may not have info on the entire web but it helped in in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The [WhoISrequest Domain History Checker](http://whoisrequest.org/history/) seems much more comprehensive than the [DNS History](https://dnshistory.org/) site. I looked up information on a couple of domain names that I've had registered for over a decade using both tools. DNS History showed information for the first one I checked indicating that its information, which is out of date, was last updated on 2010-08-11. For the other it reported "Sorry this domain was not found". Also, it only has data from 2009 onwards, whereas the WhoISrequest site has information going back to 2002.

You can also find historical information for the name servers and registrars used for a domain name through the [who.is Search Domain DNS and Name Server Information](http://who.is/dns) page. When you put a domain name in the search field, and click on "Search DNS and Name Servers", you will see information on the  name servers, SOA record, DNS records, including the mail exchanger (MX) servers for the domain. From that page, if you click on the History tab above that information, you will see past domain name registrars and name servers associated with the domain.